# Where is the modifiers tab on the graph editor when trying to modify point light brightness?

Tags: modifiers, lighting, keyframes

[image: Graph Editor]

I recently followed a fairly recent tutorial about creating candle flame, and one aspect was adding a "flickering" point light to simulate the flame light. In the tutorial they add a keyframe to the point light's brightness, and then use the graph editor to add a noise modifier for the flickering effect. When I add a keyframe to my point light's value and open the graph editor, all I see are "tool" "options" and "arrange" tabs, and no "modifiers" tab shows. Is this a change in Blender 3.6? It's not vital, but I would like to know if this is a change and if so how can I create a similar effect differently. I saw a link in which someone said lights can't be edited in the graph editor, but I've seen a couple of tutorials in which they definitely accessed a modifier tab after creating a keyframe on the light.

Comment: You need to make your editor bigger horizontally and press N or click on the arrow in the top right corner

Comment: In the image you provided you don't have the Graph Editor open. You should find that with the Graph Editor open when you enter a keyframe the tabs F-Curve, Modifiers, and View appear on the right side of it.

Comment: Thanks, I did a little more experimenting and realized I hadn't opened it far enough. Your comments are appreciated.